# Get saved search result through column index using suitescript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am using Map/Reduce script which loads a saved search in "getInputData" function. My client wants the saved search to be dynamic, means he will create saved search based on their need, so the saved search result column will change. In that case, I need to pull the first column index instead of column name in "Map" stage. But its not working for me. The below is the script I tried.

```
function getInputData() {
    var dsParam = runtime.getCurrentScript();
    var searchParam = dsParam .getParameter({name: 'custscript_myck_gen'});
    var dsSearch = search.load({
        id: searchParam
    }); 
    return dsSearch;
}
function map(context) {
    var searchResults = JSON.parse(context.value);
    var value = searchResults.getValue(searchResults.columns[0]);
}
```

But nothing works. So anyone can please help to get the field value through column index. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good practice to log context.value during development so you can see exactly what you're dealing with.

```
log.debug({
    title: 'Map',
    details: JSON.stringify(context.value)
});

var result = JSON.parse(context.value);        
var firstColumn = Object.keys(result.values)[0];

log.debug({
    title: firstColumn,
    details: JSON.stringify(result.values[firstColumn])
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it that way. There are no indexes in the result. The result of JSON stringify|parse is that each row looks like:

```
{
 recordType:'recordtype',
 id: recordId,
 values:{
    listRecordColumnName : {value:number, text:"text"},
    simpleColumName : text
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @bknights for the confirmation. Since I tried this to achieve in the map/reduce context.